# shouldComponentUpdate is not never called

Tags: reactjs

Please have a look at my code. I try to limit re-render of given stateless component but doing this found that shouldComponentUpdate is never called. I have removed wrapper from styledComponents (what was reported to be a case for someone before) but still is definitely not called.
Besides all, one could write an article on catches of this functions

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleSearchForm from './RenderGoogleSearchForm.js';
import ButtonWithMessage from './ButtonWithMessage.js';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default class RenderTableOverHead extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('shoulItdUpdate');
    return false;
  }

  render(){
    console.log('render overhead');
    const wrapstyle = 'd-flex align-items-center justify-content-center border-none'

  const Button = {
    // lots of defined buttons
  }

  return(

    <div className = {wrapstyle}> 
      {!this.props.isHiddenReturnButton && <Button.ReturnToPreliminarySearch />}
      {!this.props.isHiddenWelcomeButton && <Button.Welcome />}
      {!this.props.isHiddenFailureMsg && <Button.SearchFailure />}
      {!this.props.isHiddenResultsMsg && <Button.SearchResults /> }
      {(this.props.isConnectionOK >0||this.props.isConnectionOK===undefined) && <Button.ConnectionError /> }
      {!this.props.isHiddenInputForm && <GoogleSearchForm  FetchBooks = {this.props.FetchBooks} /> }
      {!this.props.isHiddenFilterToggleButton && <Button.FilterShowPrompt />}
  </div>
)}}
```

As requested - that is called by parent like this:

```
import RenderTableOverHead from './components/RenderTableOverHead.js';
```

below it is packed with its props to form new function

```
  const Overhead = ()=>{return(  

      <RenderTableOverHead 

      isHiddenInputForm={ this.state.isHiddenInputForm}
      isHiddenWelcomeButton={this.state.isHiddenWelcomeButton}
      ShowGoogleSearch={this.handleWelcomeButtonClick}
      //SubmitInputDataToParentState={this.fetchBooks}
      FetchBooks ={this.fetchBooks}
      isHiddenResultsMsg={this.state.isHiddenResultsMsg}
      isHiddenFailureMsg={this.state.isHiddenFailureMsg}
      toggleFilterVisibility={this.toggleFilterVisibility}
      numberOfResults ={catalog.TotalNumberOfBooks}
      numberOfPages =/*{_.last(TableWithPageNumbers)}*/{catalog.NumberOfPages}
      currentPageNumber ={catalog.CurrentPageNumber}
      //currentPage ={this.Page}//tu podmieniony numer strony jest kosztem powyższego
      isConnectionOK={this.state.connectionStatus}
      //errorStatus ={this.state.errorStatus}
      //errorMessage ={this.state.errorMessage}
      //handleError={this.handleError}
      isHiddenReturnButton={this.state.isHiddenReturnButton}
      isHiddenFilterToggleButton={this.state.isHiddenFilterToggleButton}
      />


);}
```

and is returned  like that (here its named Overhead)

```
return(

        <div className='container'>
        <Overhead />
        <Pagination />
        {isDataLoaded && 
           <div className = {cardStyle}>
           <table className = {tableStyle}>
                <thead className = {tableHeaderStyle}>
                <Headline />     
                {Filtration}            
                </thead>
                <TableBody />     
       </table>
       </div>};
       </div>)
```

Comment: If it does not execute, it means that no props nor state was changed.

Comment: when are you expecting it to be called

Comment: Ok, more about how it works and why I ask you: that could be correct that props are not changed. However, state of its parent changes and that leads apparently to re-render of this component (beacuse this component is rendered in render function of his parent). This component  re-renders what I see from log(not only, but let's keep things simple). So far I was sure that if shouldComponentUpdate returns false there is no render. And also - that before render that function is checked. That example at this moment shows me that perhaps my understanding was wrong.  But why?

Answer (score 0):

I‘ll give it a shot in that I’m not  sure what the problem is, but here are some things that I see that do not seem idiomatic to me, and may trip react off somehow.

- first, review the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) on the lifecycle method: it states that a rerender may happen under certain conditions even though sCU returns false
- the „lots of defined buttons“ looks *quite suspicious* as a performance hog. It looks like you’re rebuilding a bunch of components on every render. This is most likely static information and can be kept elsewhere.
- the wrapping of the actual component into another lambda which then closes over the outer state **and yet** is then used as a react component looks **super suspicious**. Simplify that code, e.g. by using the `RenderTableOverhead` directly at the right position. Also, don’t call the component itself *RenderSomething*... think of it more as a declaration of a piece of UI.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is very, very interesting comment for me. I suspect (and will check immy) that problem lies in the third point - the component after encapsulating in another function is no longer 100% itself and something between itself and some undefined entity

Comment: That was the case !!!! now works like charm (nearly - but now i see the way to go on). Thank you also for other comments, while there is a lot about JS best practices it is not so easy with React! I learn IT by mysel, by the way, and perhaps not always from best sources

Comment: If you ever plan to be in Warsaw be sure of beer :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's sum up. In my case the objective was to prevent unneccesary re-renders of given component.

The solution was
1. to use raw component (thanks flq)
2. to compare as follows in shouldComponentUpdate:

```
return (JSON.stringify(this.props) !=JSON.stringify(nextProps));
```

There were functions among props and perhaps that is why simple comparison led to misleading - in this specific case - results (as well as use of PureComponent).
Thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: Just note that the documentation advises *against* doing a deep comparison, as the stringification and comparison can actually be more expensive than calling the render method - keep expensive computations away from the render method and you'll seldomly need `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: In my very particular case other comparision led to misleading results. I have written loop to compare one by one entries in thisProps and nextPros, and that showed me that all are equal; while when I compared whole ones these were different. In my case it led to render, while the above meet my expectations as per result. Strange, however.

Comment: However it will be rewiritten, so that pros which are functions will not be compared at all