# shouldComponentUpdate() is not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### Problem

I've parent class which contains list of items and renders component for each item of the list. When some item has been changed (even only one), all items in the list are being rerendered.

So I've tried to implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`. I am using `console.log()` to see if it is called but I can't see the log. I've found question [shouldComponentUpdate is not never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631597/shouldcomponentupdate-is-not-never-called) and tried to return `return (JSON.stringify(this.props) !=JSON.stringify(nextProps));` but component still renders itself again. So I've tried just to `return false` (like do not ever update) but it still does. As the last try I've used `PureComponent` but it is still being rerendered.

---

#### Question

How can I stop children re-rendering if the parent list changes and why is ShouldComponentUpdate never called?

---

#### Edit

I've noticed something what I didn't mention in question, I'm sorry for that. I am using **context**. If I don't use context -> it's ok. Is there any chance to stop re-render while using context? (I'm not using context on updated item - values of context didn't change).

---

#### Example

I've **parent class** which iterates list and renders TaskPreview component for each item of list:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component
{
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         tasks: {},
      };
   }

   onTaskUpdate=(task)=>
      this.setState(prevState => ({
         tasks: {...prevState.tasks, [task._id]: task}
      }));

   // ... some code

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
             {(!Object.entries(this.props.tasks).length)
                ? null
                : this.props.tasks.map((task,index) => 
                     <TaskPreview key={task._id} task={task} onChange={this.onTaskUpdate}/>
             })}
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

and I've children **TaskPreview** class:

```
class TaskPreview extends React.Component
{
   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        console.log('This log is never shown in console');
        return false; // just never!
   }

   render() {
        console.log('task rendered:',this.props.task._id); // indicates rerender
        return(<div>Something from props</div>);
   }
}

TaskPreview.contextType = TasksContext;
export default TaskPreview;
```

---

As @Nicolae Maties suggested I've tried to use Object.keys for iteration instead of direct map but it still doesn't call "shouldComponentUpdate" and still being re-rendered even if there is no changes.

Updated code:

```
render() {
      return (
         <div>
             {(!Object.entries(this.props.tasks).length)
                ? null
                : Object.keys(this.props.tasks).map((key,index) => {
                     let task = this.props.tasks[key];
                     <TaskPreview key={task._id} task={task}/>
                }
             })}
         </div>
      )
   }
```

Comment: You are using `.map()` over an object, You should do `Object.keys(this.props.tasks/this.props.state).map()....`. Or use Object.entries as above

Comment: @NicolaeMaties I've tried your solution but nothing has changed. Provided an example in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component is being re-rendered because of `.contextType`.

```
TaskPreview.contextType = TasksContext;
```

Also as is mentioned in documentation:

> The propagation from Provider to its descendant consumers (including `.contextType` and `useContext`) **is not subject to the shouldComponentUpdate method**, so the consumer is updated even when an ancestor component skips an update. Source: [reactjs.org/docs/context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

You have to use `context` somehow else or do not use it at all.
You can use `Context.Consumer` which won't force re-render of current component but it might force re-render of its children.

```js
<TasksContext.Consumer>
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
</TasksContext.Consumer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return (JSON.stringify(this.props) != JSON.stringify(nextProps));` in your `shouldComponentUpdate()` life cycle, try specifying tasks object like  this `return (JSON.stringify(this.props.tasks) != JSON.stringify(nextProps.tasks));`

Comment: Thank you for response. I've tried this too but the problem is that `shouldComponentUpdate` is not being called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe react is creating new instances of your component and replaces the old instances with them. That's why you're probably not getting your lifecycle method invoked. That can happen if the `key` property you're assigning in the map always changes.

Comment: Key is `task._id` which is not being changed.

Answer (score 0):

use from pureComponent and array as state:

```
class Dashboard extends React.PureComponent
{
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         tasks: this.props.tasks
      }
   }

   onTaskUpdate=(task)=>
      this.setState(prevState => ({
         tasks: [...prevState.tasks, task] // render only new task
      }));

   render() {
       const {tasks} = this.state
      return (
         <div>
               {tasks.map(task => <TaskPreview key={task._id} task={task} />)}
         </div>
      )
   }
}

class TaskPreview extends React.PureComponent
{
   render() {
        console.log('task rendered:',this.props.task._id); // indicates rerender
        return(<div>Something from props</div>);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does array state really helps at all? I would like to use Object because I'm using Object keys in a lot of functions. Accessing value from object by a key (like `tasks[index]`) is constant time complexity O(1) but find in array (like `tasks.find(...)`) is linear time complexity O(n) which is much slower.

Comment: @JaxProx, find in array by index is constant time complexity O(1) like tasks[index].

Comment: @JaxProx, finding in object(dictionary) by key is equal to finding item in array by index.

Comment: Are you sure? As I know the `find(()=> something === anything)` tests every value by a function which have you specified (it means it will do it N times which is O(N)).

Btw. at this moment I've tried to set `let tasks = Object.values(this.props.tasks);` and then loop it by `map()` as you wrote but It's still re-rendering.

Comment: @JaxProx, you dont need finding in array by "string compare". for example :{tasks.map(task => <TaskPreview onClick={() => handleClick(task.index)} />

Comment: Well this isn't point of this problem at all. Thank you for your advice with array but it didn't help. There must be problem somewhere else. Btw. you are pointing out the rendering by map (which is still O(N), for array and for object too). I'm talking about finding it - like, i need to get some task: `tasks.find((el)=>el.id === myId)` which is again O(N).

Comment: I have no insistence on using the array, you can use the object, and task id as the key: `{tasks.map(task => <TaskPreview onClick={() => handleClick(task.Id)} />`

Comment: It's still map function with render but not finding.

Comment: Also if you store tasks in object as key value, to find tasks by id in handleClick function : `const { tasks } = this.state; var task = tasks[task_id] --> O(1) complexy time

Answer (score 0):

In the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method of your `TaskPreview` component, you should check if the next props have changes in comparison to the current props. Then if there are changes, return `true` to update the component, otherwise `false`.

The following example compares all the fields of props object with the new props object. But you can only check the props you are interested in.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return  !!(Object.keys(nextProps).find(key => nextProps[key] !== this.props[key]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response but it still doesn't help. Your idea is right but `console.log` in that function is not even being fired so I think the whole function is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below code snippet, `shouldComponentUpdate` worked as I expected. Could you share your Dashboard initial props ?

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      tasks: {}
    };
  }

  onTaskUpdate = task =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      tasks: { ...prevState.tasks, [task._id]: task }
    }));

  // ... some code

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!Object.entries(this.props.tasks).length
          ? null
          : Object.keys(this.props.tasks).map((key, index) => {
              let task = this.props.tasks[key];
              return (
                <TaskPreview
                  key={task._id}
                  task={task}
                  onChange={this.onTaskUpdate}
                />
              );
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TaskPreview extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log("This log is never shown in console");
    return nextProps.task._id != this.props.task._id;
  }

  render() {
    console.log("task rendered:", this.props.task); // indicates rerender
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.props.onChange(this.props.task)}>
        Something from props
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

my initial props for Dashboard component is :

```
 <Dashboard  tasks={{test:{_id:'myId', description:'some description'}}}/>
```